# Java - multiplication of variables through parameters

Tags: java, parameters, multiplication

what is the best method of calculating the product of integer variables through method parameters? I have tried using mathematical symbols such as '*' to get a result but nothing has been successful and I am lost for answers. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
int productOfThreeNumbers(int number1, int number2, int number3){
        productOfThreeNumbers(number1 * number2 * number3);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Show us your attempts and maybe we could help you then

Comment: I doubt it's the math that's the problem.  It's much more likely that your attempt to "get a result" is somehow screwed up (forgot to return a value, tried to assign return value to a parameter, etc.).  However, it's impossible to say without seeing your code.  Attempting to describe your code is nearly always pointless.  You need to [edit] your question to include the relevant code and what, exactly, your problem is with it, including any compile errors, full stack traces, expected vs actual output, etc.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to obtain an integer value from a multiplication of integers you could try

```
    public Integer mult(int a,int b){
           int c = a*b;
           return c;
    }
```

If you want to obtain a double value you could use:

```
    public double mult(int a,int b){
           double n1 = (double) a;
           double n2 = (double) b;
           double c = n1*n2;
           return c;
    }
```

you call the method with:

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = mult(a,b);
```

or

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    double c = mult(a,b);
```

depending on which method you are using.

But looking at your code just do:

```
    int productOfThreeNumbers(int number1, int number2, int number3){
    return (number1 * number2 * number3);
    }
```

Comment: Try your code with division instead of multiplication - you might notice that you lose precision with casting you use in last example. Use double parameters or cast both operands before the division to have the proper precision.

Comment: just edited my answer, thanks for telling. i didn't pay too much attention to the fact that not casting the integers to double may lose precision of the multiplication for the return value

Comment: With the multiplication everything seems to be ok, but I just wanted to warn you that, when using this type of casting with division instead of multiplication, you can make yourself some troubles. I think there was nothing wrong with your code actually, but I thought this might be a good place to point that this code works well with multiplication, but may nor very well with division. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Define TriFunction

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TriFunction<A,B,C,R> {
    R apply(A a, B b, C c);
}
```

Then, use it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TriFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer> triMult = (x,y,z) -> x*y*z;
        System.out.println(triMult.apply(2, 1, 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Pressed to choose, I'd define `TriFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>
  triMult = (x, y, z) -> (long)x * y * z;`